# Azure media services while encoding Job gives JobState.Error for .wmv file

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

For Azure media services encoding task, The status says processing.... for several times and then goes to error state.There is no error message shown. 
I am following a tuts from this https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/media-services/#encode-asset
input file size is less than 4Mb and cloudblobclient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 2

```
   IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("My encoding job");
                    IMediaProcessor processor = GetMediaProcessor(_context,"Windows Azure Media Encoder");
                    ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My encoding task",processor, "H.264 256k DSL CBR",TaskCreationOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);

                    task.InputMediaAssets.Add(assetToBeProcessed); //where assetToBeProcessed is the IAsset Ref. 
                    task.OutputMediaAssets.AddNew("Outputasset",true, AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);
                    job.Submit();
                    CheckJobProgress(_context,job.Id);
```

---

```
      private static void CheckJobProgress(CloudMediaContext _context,string jobId)
            {
                bool jobCompleted = false;
                const int JobProgressInterval = 20000;
     while (!jobCompleted)
                {
                    IJob theJob = GetJob(_context,jobId); //brings the desired jobid
     switch (theJob.State)
                    {
                        case JobState.Finished: jobCompleted = true;break;
                        case JobState.Queued:
                        case JobState.Scheduled:
                        case JobState.Processing:
                                          break;
                        case JobState.Error:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(JobProgressInterval);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get more information as for why your job has failed by using the following code where you find the job by Id and then print the info for all of the tasks there.

```
var context = CloudMediaContext(acc, key);
var job = context.Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == id).Single();

Console.WriteLine("  Job ID: " + job.Id);
Console.WriteLine("  Name: " + job.Name);
Console.WriteLine("  State: " + job.State);

      foreach (var task in job.Tasks)
      {
             Console.WriteLine("  Task Id: " + task.Id);
             Console.WriteLine("  Name: " + task.Name);
             Console.WriteLine("  Progress: " + task.Progress);
             Console.WriteLine("  Configuration: " + task.Configuration);
             Console.WriteLine("  Running time: " + task.RunningDuration);
        if (task.ErrorDetails != null)
        {
            foreach (var errordetail in task.ErrorDetails)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("  Error Message:" + errordetail.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("  Error Code:" + errordetail.Code);
            }
        }
       }
```